# How to store Kleopatra PGP keys on USB drive?

Tags: pgp, usb-flash-drive

I'm using Kleopatra (actually gpg4win) on Windows. I've created PGP Private keys, and I would like to store them on my usb stick (e.g. be able to encrypt files only if the private key is available - that is, if the usb stick is in the drive).

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot move single keys or even keypairs, but you can move the entire keyring:

1. Move GnuPG data directory (`~/.gnupg`; on Windows `%APPDATA%\.gnupg`) to your chosen location.

   - For extra security, copy and secure-wipe instead of just moving (which does an insecure deletion).
2. Set the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable to the new location.

   1. *System Properties → Advanced → Environment Variables*. Alternatively, in Windows 7, search for "environ" in Control Panel.
   2. Click *Add*, enter *`GNUPGHOME`* as name and the new path as value.

      - For example, `E:\private\gnupg` or `C:\mnt\jwir3 flash drive\GnuPG` or whatever the hell you moved your keys to.
   3. The currently running programs *will not* see your changes. Exception: Windows Shell (`explorer.exe`), which receives a change notification. So you need to close Kleopatra and restart it from the Start menu.

EDIT: Looks like it's actually the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable, rather than `GNUPG_HOME`

Answer (score 3):

I tried the GNUPGHOME directory and it mostly works but if you ever have another installation of GPG all hell breaks loose and it will create some problems. A better solution I happened upon is to download and install the full gpg4win download, then run mkportable --full [somedir] to create a portable install. Copy that to your USB or truecrypt drive and then uninstall gpg. The home directory is where you copy all your existing keyring files if any.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using Kleopatra (actually gpg4win) on Windows. I've created PGP
>   Private keys, and I would like to store them on my usb stick (e.g. be
>   able to encrypt files only if the private key is available - that is,
>   if the usb stick is in the drive).

You actually don't ENcrypt files with your private keys. Normally, public-keys do the ENcryption, private keys do the DEcrpytion or signing.

You don't get advantages from carrying your private keys with you. When windows and Cleopatra are  set up properly, the keyring-files are protected by passwords. For example when using SMIME on Windows-mashines, the Keys are encrypted with your windows-password.

If someone is able to extract your private keys from your computer, he would probably also be able to install a keylogger on this PC and copy your keyrings from your USB-drive at the moment when you attach it to that PC. Anyone could write a .com that searches for .pgp-files and copies them to a specific location, when a removeable drive is mounted (via autostart-routines).

I agree that it is absolutely reasonable to backup your Keyrings from time to time and store them away, but as soon as someone steals your PGP-keyrings, you have gained nothing. What kind of USB-drives would you use? Corsair Padlocks?

Comment: My motivation for putting it on a thumb drive, or in my case: dropbox, is that I wish to not have to synchronize the keyrings in different places. DRY, etc. For that having them in a self-syncing location would be advantagous, for example a truecrypt container.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that i am using (I am using gpg4win in Win10):
Create key - private key was stored in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\private-keys-v1.d\
I have moved  (ideally purge that space also) .key files from here to my SD card and created symlinks with same names pointing to files in SD card. Now when i try to decrypt / sign anything i get Decryption failed: No secret key. Once i insert SD card back it works fine again. No need to restart Kleopatra nor GpgEX.